How can I create Meteoric Metal in blender?
so I saw this post on reddit recently but the post is 7 years old so I don't know if the OP will respond but basically I want to create meteoric metal in blender for some projects
here is the link to the reddit post for clarity on what i want to make exactly:

any advice will be appreciated https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/6wxuou/meteorite_iron_material/

Hello and welcome. This sounds like a request for free work, there are many ways to combine nodes for procedural textures, combining the use of multiple Voronoi textures.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The question seems OK to me. It is asking how to make something. Seems like a good question for BSE. @KISKAart, I really don't see how this may seem like request for free work - they are not asking for providing the result. I think people not familiar with what is possible with nodes may sometimes just not know where to start.

@MartynasŽiemys Sorry, my mistake, at first I thought the question was: "How do you get this result from reddit?"

Please be advised as Martynas said in their answer that you should never use a render as a reference for a real object, you should always strive to get a reference of the real thing, ideally several references from diferent angles, lighting setups. Otherwise you risk amplifying biases and defaults that should not exist. Cheers

Looks like some sort of scratches directional in 3 directions. I don't think it has anything to do with Meteoric metal though as that looks very different. Have a look at the real thing maybe instead of looking at someone's interpretation, but if you want to have a copy of this copy...
You could stretch some noise scaling it's coordinates and also rotate it 60° while repeating 3 times. Use Map Range or Math in Grater/Less Than modes to make the scratches sharp:

You could also mix more various noises on top or maybe to make more complex directional patterns that would then be repeated rotated.
The idea would probably be to create some more interesting metallic shader as well. This could possibly match your reference. However, you could consider getting a more realistic reference, because real meteoric iron patterns may look very differently:

Source: https://www.fossilera.com/meteorites/2-24-etched-iron-meteorite-slice-155-5-g-section-nwa-11289
